# TypeError: unknown type GstFraction

Tags: python-3.x, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, python-gstreamer

I am trying to use *Gstreamer* with python bindings in order to search for available cameras on my system. As a result I would like to obtain a list of devices with their corresponding capabilities (width, height, framerate...).

*Gstreamer* offers very useful class called **Gst.DeviceMonitor** to obtain available devices. However, I ran into problems when tying to extract capabilities from the discovered devices. Concretely, I only have troubles with obtaining capabilities **"pixel-aspect-ratio"** and **"framerate"**, which are both of **Gst.Fraction** type.

Here is a minimal code example:

```
import gi

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst

Gst.init(None)

caps = Gst.Caps.from_string('video/x-h264,width=640,height=480,framerate={30/1, 20/1, 15/1, 1/1}')
structure = caps.get_structure(0)

width = structure.get_int('width').value
height = structure.get_int('height').value
framerates = structure.get_list('framerate').array

print('width = ', width)
print('height = ', height)
for i in range(framerates.n_values):
    print(' - framerate = ', framerates.get_nth(i))
```

The following exception is thrown on the last line:

```
TypeError: unknown type GstFraction
```

I have found [here](https://gstreamer-bugs.narkive.com/hqkO3z2X/bug-681217-new-typeerror-unknown-type-gstfraction) that someone had similar issue in 2012, but I have not found any solutions. Does anybody have any suggestion?

**PS**: I am using `Python 3.5.5` and `Gstreamer 1.14.5`.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and I finally found the solution: Install the package `python3-gst-1.0`:

```
sudo apt install python3-gst-1.0
```

I'm surprised everything else worked without that package.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs just fine on Ubuntu 18:

```sh
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9

$ gst-inspect-1.0 --version
gst-inspect-1.0 version 1.14.5
```

```
width =  640
height =  480
 - framerate =  30/1
 - framerate =  20/1
 - framerate =  15/1
 - framerate =  1/1
```

So it may be a bug in the Python GStreamer/GObject introspection bindings.

Comment: I have updated Python to 3.8.6. I run the example code before and I still get the same error. I have also tried with Python 3.6.9 (just like you) and again  the result is the same. The only difference is that I am using Ubuntu 20. Do you have any other advise what might be different?